# The approximation of the variance of MLE (Cramer-Rao Lower Bound)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

This is in In Casella's [Statistical Inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptYnm.png)，page 473, the approximation of the variance of MLE (Cramer-Rao Lower Bound). I really confused with the conclusion:

$Var_{\hat{\theta}}h(\hat{\theta})$ is a consistent estimator of $Var_{\theta}h(\hat{\theta}).$

I guess the logic is

$\dfrac{[h'(\theta)]^2}{I_n(\theta)}$ is asymptotic variance of $Var_{\theta}h(\hat{\theta})$ and $Var_{\hat{\theta}}h(\hat{\theta})$ is consistent estimator of  $\dfrac{[h'(\theta)]^2}{I_n(\theta)}.$ Then  $Var_{\hat{\theta}}h(\hat{\theta})$ is a consistent estimator of $Var_{\theta}h(\hat{\theta}).$

My questions are:

1. Why $-\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta|\bf{X})\Big|_{\theta=\hat{\theta}}$ is consistent estimator $I(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{n}E_{\theta}[-\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta|\bf{X})]?$ since $E_{\theta}[-\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta|\bf{X})] \neq -\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta|\bf{X}),$ we cannot use the consistency property of MLE.
2. Why A is asymptotic variance of B and C is the consistent estimator of A => C is the consistent estimator of B?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/449787/119261.

Comment: Who the f... is the guy named Rai?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, since there is no body answering in the Cross-Validated, and I really want to someone give me the clear logic for this part.

Comment: Well you have to be patient to get an answer here. That doesn't mean you ask the same thing on multiple sites.

Comment: Let it be known that the timestamp between this post and the one on Cross-Validated is only 2 minutes apart.